# Identify MovieClip in AS3 among DisplayObjectContainer

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, movieclip, flashdevelop, displayobject

in ActionScript 3, if I loop through the children of a movie clip, it will return a DisplayObjectContainer, which is a list of DisplayObjects.

However, the AS3 typeof cannot identify MovieClip as MovieClip is now an object, instead of a data type. How can I correctly identify MovieClip?

I found 3 solutions online:

Solution 1 (the solution I am using):

> First set the MovieClip name to a
>   specific name, then in the iterate
>   process, check the name of children
>   using child.name.indexOf("specificName") > -1

Solution 2:

> use child.hasOwnProperty("numChildren") to identify a MovieClip

Solution 3:

> use 3rd party plug-in like FlashDevelop

which solution is the best? or is there any alternatives?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's actually much improved and simplified in AS3. You can simply use the "is" operator:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < containerObj.numChildren; i++) {
    if(containerObj.getChildAt(i) is MovieClip) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

The [Flash livedocs for this topic](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000045.html) have some more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Use `is` keyword as richleland suggested.

Apologies in advance for nitpicking but I couldn't resist saying that:

- `getChildAt` returns `DisplayObject`, not `DisplayObjectContainer` as you suggested in the question.
- `numChildren` is a property of `DisplayObjectContainer` class and `MovieClip` is not the only derived class of it. `Loader`, `Stage` and `Sprite` extends `DisplayObjectContainer`. `MovieClip` is a subclass of `Sprite`. Hence numChildren trick will fail if you wanted to use movieclip specific actions like `gotoAndStop` on the child.
- Proper way of comparing the name would be `child.name == "specificName"` unless you are using "specificName" as a prefix or suffix for all the children that are movieclips.